# Cannot write custom object via Soap API, getting INVALID_TYPE: sObject type is not supported

Tags: custom-object, soap-api

We have created a new custom object in our SF account named "Product License". We are trying to write new data to it via SF Soap API. However, when I try to call the update method, I get the following error message:

```
INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'Product_License__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

What I have tried so far to fix the issue:

- Confirmed that the API name of the object is "Product_License__c";
- Updated the WSDL files with the latest versions;
- Confirmed that the user has API access;
- Confirmed that the object deployment status is "Deployed";

However, I am still unable to write a new instance of this object. Any suggestions on what else I can do to troubleshoot this issue?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Does the user have CRUD/FLS on the object?

Comment: @DavidReed that was indeed the problem. The user didn't have permissions to access the new object. Permissions updated and now it is working. Thank you!

Comment: @DavidReed please add an answer to the question and I'll mark it as answered to give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the authenticated user does not have CRUD access to the object. The WSDL can contain a reference to the object even if the actual connected user does not have permission to see it.